# JWT Signature Verification Fails with Public Key from Microsoft JWKS Endpoint in CakePHP

Tags: php, json, cakephp, jwt

I am working on a CakePHP application where I need to validate JWTs issued by Microsoft Azure AD. I have fetched the public keys from Microsoft's JWKS endpoint, converted one of them to PEM format, and tried to verify the JWT signature, but I keep getting a "Signature verification failed" error. I've also tried validating the token using jwt.io with the same result.

Here's the process I'm following:

1. **Fetch the JWKS**: I'm retrieving the JWKS from
   [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/discovery/v2.0/keys](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant-id%7D/discovery/v2.0/keys).
2. **Convert JWK to PEM**: I've converted the JWK to PEM format using an
   online tool.
3. **JWT Decoding**: Using the Firebase JWT PHP library for decoding and
   verifying the JWT.
4. **Error Encountered**: The JWT library throws a "Signature verification
   failed" error.
   Here's the relevant part of my code:

   $accessToken = $request->getHeaderLine('Authorization');
   $accessToken = str_replace('Bearer ', '', $accessToken);

   ```
       if (empty($accessToken)) {
           throw new UnauthorizedException('No token provided');
       }
       $jwtParts = explode('.', $accessToken);
       if (count($jwtParts) > 0) {
           $jwtHeaderJson = base64_decode($jwtParts[0]);
       }


   try {
       $jwksUri = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/discovery/v2.0/keys'; 
       $jwksJson = file_get_contents($jwksUri);
       $jwks = json_decode($jwksJson, true);

       // Add 'alg' parameter if missing and log the keys
       foreach ($jwks['keys'] as $key => $value) {
           if (!isset($jwks['keys'][$key]['alg'])) {
               $jwks['keys'][$key]['alg'] = 'RS256'; // Default algorithm used by Azure
           }
           Log::debug("Key $key: " . json_encode($jwks['keys'][$key]));
       }

       $keys = JWK::parseKeySet($jwks);
       $pemKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
       . "MIIBIjxxxxxxx\n"
       . "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

       $decodedToken = JWT::decode($accessToken, new Key($pemKey, 'RS256'));
   ```

**Questions:**

1. Am I converting the JWK to PEM correctly? *(I've already tried another approach, but Microsoft is not providing an "alg" param -> (JWK::parseKeySet($jwks))*
2. Is there any known issue with JWTs from Azure AD and PHP libraries?
3. Could there be an issue with how the JWT is being issued by Azure AD?

Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.